# wpf surface 2.0 ElementMenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, pixelsense

I tried to implement a simple Menu with wpf for the surface 2.0/pixelsense.

```
<s:SurfaceWindow x:Class="MenuTrial.SurfaceWindow1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008" 
xmlns:MenuTrial="clr-namespace:MenuTrial"
xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:MenuTrial.Properties"
Title="MenuTrial"
>



 <Grid Name="MenuGrid" Height="102" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <s:ScatterView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <s:ScatterView.Resources>
            <Image x:Shared="false" x:Key="IconPhoto" Source="Resources\Icons\photo.png"/>
            <Image x:Shared="false" x:Key="IconCopy" Source="Resources\Icons\copy.png"/>
        </s:ScatterView.Resources>


        <s:ScatterViewItem Height="139"
                           Width="224"
                           Orientation="-23"
                           Background="#FF787878">
        <s:ElementMenu
            Name="MainMenu"
            ActivationMode="AlwaysActive"
            ActivationHost="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type s:ScatterViewItem}}}"
        >
        <s:ElementMenuItem Header="Menu1"/>
      <s:ElementMenuItem Header="Menu2"/>
             <s:ElementMenuItem Header="{x:Static Resources:Resources.IconPhoto}" Icon="{StaticResource IconPhoto}">
                  <s:ElementMenuItem Header="{x:Static Resources:Resources.Copy}" Icon="{StaticResource IconCopy}" Command="{x:Static MenuTrial:SurfaceWindow1.ShowMessageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
                  <s:ElementMenuItem Header="Menu 3.2" />
                  <s:ElementMenuItem Header="Menu 3.3"/>
            </s:ElementMenuItem>
    </s:ElementMenu>
        </s:ScatterViewItem>
    </s:ScatterView>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textMessage" Width="500" Margin="40" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Segoe360" FontSize="17" />
</Grid>
```

The problem is, I get an unknown bild mistake. Key can't be NULL or something would it be in english. At the Header="{x:Static Resources....

It is exactly like in the Surface samples. I just wanted to show a message when the menu item was clickt.

Can anyone please help me? Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you define this `MenuItem` under `Resources` section you need to provide it with a `x:Key` value. Resources can't be declared without Key -

```
<s:ElementMenuItem Header="{x:Static Resources:Resources.IconPhoto}"
                   Icon="{StaticResource IconPhoto}"
                   x:Key="MyMenuItem">
                  ....
</s:ElementMenuItem>
```

Comment: I have the x:Key already at the beginning declared

<s:ScatterView.Resources>
                <Image x:Shared="false" x:Key="IconPhoto" Source="Resources\Icons\photo.png"/>
                <Image x:Shared="false" x:Key="IconCopy" Source="Resources\Icons\copy.png"/>
            </s:ScatterView.Resources>

Comment: You need to declare it for every Resource you are placing in the dictionary. In case you are placing the MenuItem in Resources section, you need to set it for too.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. How does the key help me to finde the ressource? The toolip says Cannot resolve sybol 'Resources' where it elsewhere (e.g. Icon) says MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionTypeNode.

Comment: Can you show more code of your xaml? It's difficult what you are trying to achieve without more details.

Comment: Now the whole xaml code is online. I hope you unterstand what I was trying to do.
thx